# How to substring a string Python from a specific index in Python?

Tags: python, string

what is the best way to substring a string in Python starting from a specific character ?

For example, if `val = "s2*20"`, how to get the substring of `val` which is after `*`. The result should be `res = 20`.

PS: We assume that all the strings contains `*` with different lengths. However, we don't know the exact index of `*`.

Comment: What are you stuck with, finding the index of the asterisk, or taking a slice of your string?

Comment: could be there a string `s2**20***word` ? what should be the result?

Comment: You should define what _best way_ means. Fastest? Least code? Asking for something _best_ usually involves opinions...

Comment: @ChristianKönig best way means fastest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> val = 's2*20'
>>> val.split('*')[1]
'20'
```

Depending on what you want, you may want to check for `'*'` inside your string, or just taking everything after the first occurrence of `'*'`, but hard to guess without more info. This might be a plausible scenario:

```
>>> def rest(s):
...     return s.split('*',1) if '*' in s else s
...
>>> rest('hi')
'hi'
>>> rest('hi there * wazzup * man')
['hi there ', ' wazzup * man']
```

**Edit:** as pointed out in the comment by @Jon (no, not Skeet), using [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) is better in every way.

```
>>> val = 's2*20'
>>> val.partition('*')[2]
'20'
>>> val = 's2-20'
>>> val.partition('*')[2]
''
```

It's smoother and performs *surprisingly* good - in fact a lot better than `split`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('"s2*20".split("*")')
0.22846507105495942
>>> timeit.timeit('"s2-20".split("*")')
0.1685205617091654
>>> timeit.timeit('"s2*20".partition("*")')
0.1475598294296372
>>> timeit.timeit('"s2-20".partition("*")')
0.09512975462482132
```

[image: py split vs. partition performance]

Comment: `val.partition('*')[2]` is safer as it'll guarantee the index lookup won't fail if the split character isn't provided (you'll get an empty string instead) and more efficient as it'll split at most once implicitly...

Comment: The problem with your `rest` function is that it now performs a containment test which for where the delimiter is towards the end or not present is an unnecessary operation. `str.partition` avoids all that for you...

Comment: @JonClements: I've never heard of `partition`, thought it was fairly new or obscure, but see it's been around since 2.5. You're absolutely right, that is a much better solution, will make a mental note of forever using partition, thanks!

Comment: To make the timeits slightly more fair and equivalent  - you may wish to provide the max split parameter (eg 1)

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks !

Comment: @JonClements: the `maxsplit=1` has no performance impact at all (in this case).

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case:

```
val[val.index('*')+1:]
```

Find the first occur position of `*`, and take a slice from there.

or:

```
val.split('*', 1)[-1]
```

The tells to split string only once with delimiter, if you want everything after the first `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.split`:

```
>>> val = "s2*20"
>>> res = val.split("*")[1]
>>> res
'20'
```

Using `str.index`:

```
>>> val[val.index("*")+1:]
'20'
```

Using `re.findall`:

```
>>> re.findall("\*(\d+)", val)[0]
'20'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.index` to get the index of the asterisk and then use indexing to substring the full string.

```
s = "s2*20"
ind = s.index('*')
substring = s[ind+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you get a String like var="s*s*s*s*20" which * do you want?
If you have an accurate index of the *'s sequence in the String, I think it would be a possible way like this:

```
    string_test = "var num=s*s*t*15"
    # In case you want the substring after the last * 
    sub_string = string_test[string_test.rindex('*') + 1:] 
    print sub_string
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are certain that the character is in the string the one I use most often looks like this:

```
mystring=mystring[mystring.find('*'):]
```

this will slice your string from that character onward without creating an additional datastructure